# "Bump one's head on something" vs. "against something"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, prepositions

Can anyone help me understand the difference between bumping one's head *on* something and bumping it *against* it? Is there any substantial difference or are they used interchangeably?

Comment: Try the ELL site for this one.  Please expand "sth" to a normal word.

Comment: e.g. "to bump your head on/against the ceiling/shelf/door"

Comment: (1) click "Edit".  spell out "sty" properly.  (2) this question should be on the ELL site, good luck!

Comment: @Joe I disagree about this being an ELL question. The way it is phrased makes it seem like one, but the underlying question is a good one. There _is_ a difference between bumping your head on the door and bumping your head against the door, but I’m having quite a hard time figuring out even to myself what precisely that difference is.

Comment: Janus BJ ... ok !

Comment: This is exactly what I am interested in. What is the difference? Can anyone help with this one?

Comment: In some contexts, *on* could be more specific than *against.*

Comment: In my experience, 'on' is used when individual body parts are being bumped "on something" while 'against' is used when the body as a whole is bumping "against something".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Bump on something" refers to the physical act of running into something. The most common usage of "against something" seems to be as a metaphor, as in "She bumped against the glass ceiling".

Comment: *She bumped against something* is a different construction from *She bumped her head on/against something.* In addition, when I collide with the furniture, I never bump on the furniture, but I bump against it.